# What's up with the "Reopen Votes" Review Queue?

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

There seems to be an issue/bug with the "Reopen Votes" review queue at the moment. When I go there, I get this error:

[image]

I've seen this once or twice before (on various queues) but the problem normally goes away after a few minutes or retries. This time, it's been persisting for over an hour already.

All other queues still 'open' to me are working fine.

Comment: No repro for me, I'm on Chrome/Win10 and in Western Europe

Comment: It let me do about 4 or 5 reviews OK and then started giving this error. Firefox, macOS

Comment: @rene I'm using Edge/Win10. Could it be a cache or cookie issue?

Comment: I can reproduce on Chrome/Win10, Western Europe. Other queues are working for me.

Comment: @greg That's how it went for me, too. Did some, then it went west.

Comment: I wonder if it is restricted to reviewing, I've also seen a few random failures on comment voting.

Comment: Okay, it is intermittent, I just reproduced the problem

Comment: @rene Yeah - I just managed 2 (same PC, slightly different location) then hit my daily limit (so me no more guinea-pig till tomorrow).

Comment: I can repro this too, very intermittent and occurred when submitting a review. The server returned an HTTP 302 redirect to `/error?aspxerrorpath=/review/task-reviewed/<review-id>`

Comment: It's also broken on Meta Stack Exchange: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337692/295232

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been fixed. Reopen queue should be open for business again.

For those interested in the details, this was related to post notices. An update was recently made in post notices to the text being shown in the review queue describing the reason why a post was closed. I forgot to also account for the case where an obsolete close reason was used when closing the post (a situation that can appear in the reopen queue when looking at a post closed a long time ago).